# Acceder a datos de una relacion desde las vistas

Tags: laravel, orm

tengo  consulta que tal vez alguien de seguro ya ha trabajado: tengo una tabla personal con un cliente_id y una tabla clientes (se relacionan por medio del cliente id) ahora bien, el cliente tiene una cuenta de acceso, se loguea y necesito poder acceder a los datos de la empresa a la que esta asociado, por ahora usando {{auth()->user()->name}} puedoa acceder al nombre del cliente, pero necesito traer la informacion asociada a la empresa del cliente que se loguea para usarla en diferentes vistas y formularios de su "sesion"

Entiendo que deberia partir por establecer las relaciones:

En mi modelo Cliente tengo la relacion asi:

```
 // 1 CLIENTE TIENEN MUCHOS FUNCIONARIOS
    public function funcionarios()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Personal');
    }
```

En el Modelo Personal:

```
 //1 FUNCIONARIO PERTENECE A UNA EMPRESA
    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Cliente');
    }
```

Y por ejemplo en una de mis vistas (ya con el user logueado) necesitaria recuperar el cliente_id del usuario, por lo cual intento asi:

```
{{$funcionarios->cliente->cliente_id}}
```

pero me dice que la variable $funcionarios no esta definida, aclaro que estoy trabajando directamente desde la vista, estoy confundido si debo trabajar esto en el controlador?...

Creo que estoy haciendo algo mal pero no logro darme cuenta de que es...

Agradezco comentarios desde ya...

Saludos

Comment: Cliente es tu modelo autenticable, digamos, el que traes en `auth()->user()`? Y cuando dices "Empresa", es lo mismo que cliente?

Comment: Cliente es la empresa, en la tabla personal almaceno el user_id (autenticable) y el cliente_id (id de la empresa)

Comment: Pero pusiste que  `auth()->user()->name` te da el nombre del cliente. Significa que en realidad sólo obtienes el nombre del usuario? Y qué tipo de relación hay entre user y personal? Por el nombre de la llave suena como que User::hasOne('Personal') y Personal::belongsTo('User')

Comment: Me confundi, con  auth()->user()->name obtengo el nombre del usuario registrado, eL ID del auth()->user() lo almaceno luego en la tabla personal (junto con cliente_id) por medio de un formulario aparte, las relaciones que me planteas las tengo asi en ambos modelos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En general, para que una variable esté definida en una vista tendrías que pasársela al helper o al Facade en un controller o en el closure de una ruta:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('bienvenida', ['nickname' => 'Nicolás']);
});
```

Eso permitiría acceder a `$nickname` en `bienvenida.blade.php`.

También podrías disponibilizar variables a todas las vistas en un middleware o un provider usando `View:share`. Por ejemplo en `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php` si el request pasa la prueba del guard, poblar cualquier vista que venga aguas abajo con el usuario logueado:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

    View::share(['user'=>auth()->user()]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Cuando defines una ruta que va directo a una vista

```
 Route::view('/', 'bienvenida');
```

Puedes usar los helpers para poblar tus variables, por ejemplo en un block `@php`

```
@php
$user = auth()->user();
@endphp

Bienvenido {{ $user->name }}
```

---

En tu caso particular, estás intentando acceder a la variable `$funcionarios` , pero el nombre sugiere que te refieres a una relación del modelo `Cliente`, así que no es lógico que la tengas si justamente es el cliente lo que buscas.

Lo que pareciera hacer falta es la relación entre `User` y `Personal`. Ya que el personal tiene una propiedad `user_id`, si ese campo es único entonces puedes declarar la relación en el modelo User

```
   public function funcionario() {
       return $this->hasOne(Personal::class);
   }
```

Que por debajo usa una convención que equivale a declarar explícitamente:

```
   public function funcionario() {
       return $this->hasOne(Personal::class, 'user_id', 'id');
   }
```

Con esto podrías hacer algo como:

```
@php
$user = auth()->user();
$funcionario = $user->funcionario;
@endphp

Bienvenido {{ $user->name }}, de la empresa {{ $funcionario->cliente->nombre }}.
```